# Viewing and Editing of XMP Information

Tags: windows, indexing, xmp

I wish to build a web application that is able to modify XMP read and edit information of image files. Is that possible to tap on XMP Information of image files in that manner?

I'll most probably be working via a Windows Server (2003), and writing in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some head-start for this from the official Adobe XMP SDK. It is available here : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html

This is a free public SDK of the XMP standard created by Adobe. The SDK is available in C/C++. The complete source is available along with the documentation. This contains all the relevant API's to manipulate XMP metadata across a variety of supported formats. This can be leveraged to port it to some other platform.